# Plural Hebrew numbers multiple vs. tens

Tags: hebrew, hebrew-bible, numbers

From what I can see, in order to make a Hebrew number tenfold, you make it plural.

שֶׁבַע (H7651) sheh'-bah is the word for seven.

שִׁבְעִים (H7657) shib-eem' is seventy.

שִׁבְעָתַיִם (H7659) shib-aw-thah'-yim is sevenfold.

If H7657 is taking H7651 and adding the plural ending -im, how would one express the concept of multiple sevens or multiple distinct groups of seven?

Does שִׁבְעִים always mean 70, or can it mean something else in certain contexts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word שִׁבְעִים (shib'iyim) occurs 91 times in the OT and always means "seventy", eg, Gen 4:24, 5:12, 5:31, 11:26, 12:4, 25:7, 46:27, 50:3, Ex 1:5, 15:27, 24:1, 24:9, 38:25, 28, Num 1:27, 2:4, 3:43, 46, 7:13, 19, 25, 31, 37, 43, etc.  It is simply the plural form of "seven" and means "seventy" as the OP points out.

The word שִׁבְעָתַיִם (shib'atayim) occurs six times in the OT and always means "seven-fold" or perhaps, "seven times", Gen 4:15, 24, Ps 12:6, 79:12, Prov 6:31, Isa 30:26.  This word in the dual form indicates that something is increased seven times or seven-fold and is used to describe the purity of God's words (Ps 12:6) or the perfect judgement of God (Ps 79:12), etc.  In Prov 6:31 it denotes the sevn-fold repayment of a theft.